# What are the transitive extensions of finite representations of cyclic groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups

This question is a generalisation of [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291644/what-are-all-the-transitive-extensions-of-cyclic-groups). Let $H$ be a finite, transitive permutation group of degree $n$. If the point stabiliser subgroup $H_n$ of degree $n-1$ is some faithful permutation representation of a cyclic group $C_k$ (with $k$ not necessarily equal to $n-1$), what can $H_n$ and $H$ be? For example, must $k$ divide $n-1$?

Comment: "with possibly more than one orbit": you probably mean "with possibly more than two orbits": the linked question is when there are two orbits ($\{x\}$ and its complement). Anyway there is not much to say: you get all pairs $(G,H)$, where $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a cyclic subgroup with trivial core.

Comment: Thank you, Yes. To be sure, I have completely rewritten the question.

Comment: Of course $k$ does not have to divide $n-1$. For example, take a dihedral group of degree $n$ in its natural action, for $n$ even. Then the point-stabiliser has order $k=2$ which does not divide $n-1$.

Comment: Note that, by the paper I cited in your previous question, we do have $k\leq n-1$. In general, not much more can be said that what YCor said.

Comment: Note that $H$ can be literally anything: simply have it act regularly on itself. (This is the case $k=1$.)